# Word Wrap Program C

Tags: c, word-wrap

At the end of Chapter 1 of *The C Programming Language*, there are a few exercises to complete. The one I am doing now asks you to make a program that wraps a long string of text into multiple lines at a specific length. The following function works 100%, aside from the last line which does not get wrapped, no matter the specified maximum width of a line.

```
// wrap: take a long input line and wrap it into multiple lines
void wrap(char s[], const int wrapline)
{
    int i, k, wraploc, lastwrap;

    lastwrap = 0; // saves character index after most recent line wrap
    wraploc = 0; // used to find the location for next word wrap

    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i, ++wraploc) {

        if (wraploc >= wrapline) {
            for (k = i; k > 0; --k) {
                // make sure word wrap doesn't overflow past maximum length
                if (k - lastwrap <= wrapline && s[k] == ' ') {
                    s[k] = '\n';
                    lastwrap = k+1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            wraploc = 0;
        }

    } // end main loop

    for (i = 0; i < wrapline; ++i) printf(" ");
    printf("|\n");
    printf("%s\n", s);
}
```

I have found the issue to be with the variable `wraploc`, which is incremented until it is greater than `wrapline` (the maximum index of a line). Once it is greater than `wrapline`, a newline is inserted at the appropriate location and `wraploc` is reset to 0.

The problem is that on the last line, `wraploc` is never greater than `wrapline`, even when it should be. It increments perfectly throughout iteration of the string, until the last line. Take this example:

```
char s[] = "This is a sample string the last line will surely overflow";
wrap(s, 15);
```

---

```
$ ./a.out
               |
this is a
sample string
the last line
will surely overflow
```

The line represents the location where it should be wrapped. In this case, `wraploc` has the value 14, when there are clearly more characters than that.

I have no idea why this is happening, can someone help me out?

(Also I'm a complete beginner to C and I have no experience with pointers so please stay away from those in your answers, thanks).

Comment: Try `for(k = i - 1; k > 0; --k)` instead of `for(k = i; k > 0; --k)`

Comment: no, doesn't make a difference @ciphermagi

Comment: I am unable to understand the use of `k - lastwrap <= wrapline`. Is this condition checking really necessary?

Comment: Also, the program works fine for `if (wraploc == wrapline)`, instead of `if (wraploc >= wrapline)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You increment `wraploc` with `i` until it reaches `wrapline` (15 in the example).
When you wrap, you backtrack from `i`, back to the last whitespace.
That means that in your next line you already have some characters between the `lastwrap` location and `i`, i.e., you can't reset `wraploc` to 0 there.
Try setting `wraploc = i-lastwrap` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I didn't recognize that fact

Answer (score 4):

Anybody who might, like me, find this question and run into a problem with new-lines in the source string.

This is my answer:

```
inline int wordlen(const char * str){
   int tempindex=0;
   while(str[tempindex]!=' ' && str[tempindex]!=0 && str[tempindex]!='\n'){
      ++tempindex;
   }
   return(tempindex);
}
void wrap(char * s, const int wrapline){

   int index=0;
   int curlinelen = 0;
   while(s[index] != '\0'){

      if(s[index] == '\n'){
         curlinelen=0;
      }
      else if(s[index] == ' '){

         if(curlinelen+wordlen(&s[index+1]) >= wrapline){
            s[index] = '\n';
            curlinelen = 0;
         }

      }

      curlinelen++;
      index++;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an adaptation of user KECG's previous answer.

Adaptations made:

- Expands the line breakable character set to include hyphen, tabs, etc

  - implements switch() to facilitate easy expansion of that character set.
- Stores results in an allocated buffer that is returned to caller.

  - We do not overwrite the breakable chars: hyphen, tab, etc, but store them in the buffer.
  - Adds newline chars to output buffer to signal line breaks
  - Disallows unwanted chars from entering buffer (like carriage return ('\r')
  - Translates tabs and places variabley defined SPACE chars into buffer.
- Ugly-breaks a long word in an unfortunate scenario. "Unfortunate scenario" defined as:

  - When NOT ugly-breaking a word would result in spaces consuming more than
    a user-defined percentage of the current line

Runnable tested code with output is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/17qz9n7n7).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#define SPACE (char)('+') /*visible representation of tab replacement for analysis */
#define TOLERANCE 0.10


void ErrorExit(char *str)
{
    puts(str);  
    exit(0);
}


/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    next_break()
    
    Algo: function does a look-ahead for a space, a hyphen... anything that
    constitutes a natural sentence break oppty.   Returns the index of 
    the break oppty to the caller.
*--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int next_break(const char * str)
{
   int done = FALSE, tempindex= -1;
   char ch;

   while(!done)
   {
       ch = str[++tempindex];
       switch( ch ) 
       {
            case 0:
            case (char)' ':
            case (char)'\n':
            case (char)'\t':
            case (char)'-':
                done = TRUE;
            break;

            default:
            break;
       }
   }
   return(tempindex);
}

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    wordwrap()
    
    Algo: parses a long string looking for line break opportunities with 
    every char. If a break oppty is found at cuurent offs, does a qwk scan ahead 
    via next_break() to see if a better oppty exists ahead. ('Better' means closer 
    to the margin but NOT past the margin)

    If no better oppty found ahead, inserts a newline into buffer & restarts the line
    count.  Else, postpones the newline until chars are read up to the better oppty.
    
    Inputs: char *src buffer needing word wrap formatting.
            int max_line_len for wrap margin.
            int pointer *ugly_breaks for returning number of middle-of-word breaks. 

    Returns a buffer having the formatted text.
*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
char *wordwrap(const char *src, const int max_line_len, int *ugly_breaks)
{
    int src_idx=0, dest_idx = 0, cur_line_len = 0, done = FALSE;
    char ch;
    char *dest = malloc(strlen(src)*3); /* Enough space for even the worst of wrap possibilities.*/ 
    int new_line_needed = FALSE;

    if(!dest)
        ErrorExit("Memory Allocation error in wordwrap");

    while(!done)
    {
        ch = src[src_idx];
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 0:
                done = TRUE;
            break;

            case (char)' ':
            case (char)'-':
                dest[dest_idx++]=ch; /* No matter what happens next, we will include this char... */
                cur_line_len++;   /* ... and so of course we need to say this. */
                /* Would the next break oppty put us past the margin/line limit? */
                if(cur_line_len + next_break(&src[src_idx+1]) >= max_line_len)
                {
                    /* A: Yes.  Take the break oppty here, Now*/
                    new_line_needed = TRUE;
                }
            break;

            case (char)'\n':
                /* NOTE:  you don't have to honor existing line breaks in the text.
                * You can comment out these next 2 lines (and remove the newline ('\n') case in 
                * function next_break()) to completely reformat paragraphs.  It's actually more 
                * aesthetic if you do, but this is an opinion, and so I leave the code here. */
                dest[dest_idx++]=ch;
                cur_line_len=0;
            break;

            case (char)'\r': /* Nope, stripping these */
            break;

            case (char)'\t': /* Tab, replace with space(s)*/    
                    
                    if(cur_line_len+1 + next_break(&src[src_idx+1]) >= max_line_len)
                    {
                        /* We have a tab as the last character of the current line.
                        * You can expect this to be rare and it is.  But if you don't 
                        * care for it, result will be disappointing sooner or later*/
                        new_line_needed = TRUE;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        /* Replace the 4s here with any tab stop you like. 8 is the standard.*/
                        int to_add = 4-((cur_line_len)%4);

                        while(to_add-- && cur_line_len < max_line_len)
                        {
                            dest[dest_idx++]=SPACE;  /* Adaptable space replacement char */
                            cur_line_len++;
                        }
                    }
            break;

            default:
                dest[dest_idx++]=ch;
                cur_line_len++;
            break;
        }
        
        /* Has one of our cases flagged a need for newline? */
        if(new_line_needed)
        {
            int space_remaining = (max_line_len-cur_line_len);
            double percent_remain = 0.0;

            new_line_needed = FALSE;

            /* We now take the newline request as advisement.  We inspect
            * the length of remaining chars on the current line before we agree.
            * If some long word is next, then we're going to break it up ugly 
            * instead of leaving a lot of unused space in our buffer/application.
            * It's merely trading one kind of ugly (unused space) for another (broken word). 
            * 
            * We want to keep going (no newline) if more than -- say 10% -- of current line 
            * would become white space by newlining right now.
            *
            * Set percent_remain tolerance lower than 10% to get more greedy
            * with space conservation but get more ugly word breaks.
            *
            * 5% (0.05) is pretty nice with an avg of only 2 ugly breaks per 
            * a paragraph with a "reasonable" margin (70 chars or more).
            *
            * Set to 100% (1.0) and you won't get any ugly breaks -- unless 
            * you encounter a Huge word that is longer than your margin limit.
            */
            if(max_line_len > 0 )
                    percent_remain = (double)space_remaining/max_line_len;
            if(percent_remain < TOLERANCE) 
            {
                /* Not much space remaining, we can newline here */
                dest[dest_idx++]='\n';
                cur_line_len = 0;
            }
        }
        /* Since we are habitually ignoring new line requests made by the cases,
        * -- AND because it is possible to get some long character sequence or word
        * which may exceed our margin -- 
        * ... check for margin overflow with every loop. */ 
        if(cur_line_len >= max_line_len)
        {
            /* We have or will overflow with next char.
            * This is called breaking the word ugly.  Sorry babe.*/
            dest[dest_idx++]='\n';
            cur_line_len = 0;
            /* Track ugly breaks for tolerance & adjusting newline rejections*/
            (*ugly_breaks)++;  
        }
        src_idx++;
    }
    dest[dest_idx++]='\0';  /* cap it */
    return dest;
}
```